# Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'int' in enum reference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums

I have the following vb.net function:

```
Public Function GetTicketDocument(ByVal vTicketNumber As Int32, ByVal vDocumentType As TicketDocumentType) As String

    Dim objO_Int As New dtIntegration_v10_r1.OmniqueManager(mobjSecurity)
    Dim strTicketFormat As String = ""
    Dim strEFILE_GUID As String = ""

    Select Case vDocumentType

        Case TicketDocumentType.tdtEstimate
            strTicketFormat = "Estimate"
        Case TicketDocumentType.tdtRepairOrder
            strTicketFormat = "RepairOrder"
        Case TicketDocumentType.tdtInvoice
            strTicketFormat = "Invoice"
    End Select
    strEFILE_GUID = objO_Int.GetTicketDocument(vTicketNumber, strTicketFormat)

    Return strEFILE_GUID

End Function
```

and when I run the aspx page that is associated with this function I get the following error

> Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'int'

and this is the line of code that it references

```
mEFile_GUID = objMain.GetTicketDocument(txtTicketNumber.Text, mTicketStage_ID);
```

one would think all you would have to do is something like this

```
mEFile_GUID = objMain.GetTicketDocument(Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketNumber.Text), mTicketStage_ID);
```

However when I do that I get this error that I have no idea how to fix

> Argument type 'int' is not assignable to parameter type 'dtlService_v10_r1.Manager.TicketDocumentType'

Has anyone encountered this before?  I can post the dll 'dtlService_v10_r1' if needed but it is quite lengthy just so you know

Oh probably some important information as well is that this is a conversion process from vb.net to c# and we are keeping the function in vb.net.  I don't know if that is needed information or not but I like to give as much information as I can

Comment: guess it is mTicketStage_ID parameter, you need to pass the enum value like TicketDocumentType.tdtEstimate

Comment: You had two problems (1 error message doesn't mean 1 problem; but that you have firstly to fix 1 problem and then see) and you fixed the first one (congrats). Now you have to take care of the second one by treating the enum as an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the 2'nd parameter that is your current problem. You need to cast it into the correct enum type.

```
Dim vTicketNumber  = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketNumber.Text)
Dim vDocumentType  = DirectCast(mTicketStage_ID, TicketDocumentType)
mEFile_GUID = objMain.GetTicketDocument(vTicketNumber, vDocumentType)
```

Comment: Thank you Magnus that was the solution.  I am not well versed in VB so that might explain it :-)